# How to get all digit summation in BigInteger Value?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have the following problem:

If n1 & n2 are natural numbers while n1 < 10 and n2 <10000.
find the summation of all digits in z where z = n1<sup>n2</sup>.

ex. `n1 = 3, n2 = 10, z= 3^10 = 59049` if you sum the digits `5+9+0+4+9= 27`. result =27
ex. `n1 = 2, n2 = 12, z= 2^12 = 4096` if you sum the digits `4+0+9+6 = 19`. result =19

And my current solution is:

```
public static long Solving(int n1, int n2) {
    if (n1 >= 0 && n2 >= 0) {
        BigInteger z = BigInteger.valueOf((long) Math.pow(n1, n2));
        long sum = 0;

        for (BigInteger i = z; i.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0; i = i.divide(BigInteger.TEN)) {
            sum += Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(i.remainder(BigInteger.TEN)));
        }
        return sum;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why all cases doesn't success in that problem?

Comment: Give a non-working case would help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual problem is `Math.pow(n1, n2)`.

Here you are treating both arguments as `double` and trying to calculate n1<sup>n2</sup> which can easily cause an overflow.

Instead you can use [BigInteger#pow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow(int)) to get rid of overflow:

```
BigInteger z = BigInteger.valueOf(n1).pow(n2);
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for help, is there a way to optimize my code, it's slower than required.. what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user10548941 Calling `BigInteger#remainder()` function is actually overhead here. You can convert `z` to string and then you can easily calculate the sum by traversing the string.

Comment: Brilliant..! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this easily by doing something like this :

Step 1. Convert n1 to BigInteger

Step 2. Use native power function of BigInteger [exponent of pow function of big integer must be int]

Step 3. Convert the result back into string

Step 4. Iterate over the string and calculate the sum of digits.

Reference : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/java_math_biginteger.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_pow.htm